# metric on SE(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, rotations

Let
$
SO(3) = \{ R  \mid RR^\top = I_3 \text{ and } \det(R) = 1 \}
$
and
$$
SE(3) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} R & {\bf t} \\ {\bf 0}^\top & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mid R \in SO(3), {\bf t} \in \mathbb{R}^3\right\}.
$$
My question is, given two matrices $H_1, H_2 \in SE(3),$ can anyone provide a formula for the geodesic distance between them?

My best guess is to add the magnitude of the rotation and the magnitude of the translation.
Then, the the distance between $H_1$ and $H_2$ is given by
$$
||H_1 - H_2|| 
= ||{\rm Rodrigues}(R_1R_2^\top)||_2 +\frac{1}{2} \left( ||{\bf t}_1 - R_2^\top {\bf t}_2||_2+ ||{\bf t}_2 - R_1^\top {\bf t}_1||_2\right),
$$
where I am using Rodrigues' formula to find the angle-axis representation for $SO(3)$ in order to easily find the magnitude of a rotation.
This is rather ad-hoc, but it at least it is zero when $H_1=H_2$, strictly positive otherwise, and symmetric.  Whether or not it obeys the triangle inequality I do not know for sure, but I think no.

[Calin Belta and Vijay Kumar's 2002 paper](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1155&context=meam_papers) seems to be relevant, but they are talking about smooth rigid motions parameterized by points in $SE(3)$, and not necessarily just looking at the absolute difference that I am interested in.  Maybe its the same, but I don't know enough differential geometry to tell.

Comment: What metric do you have in mind for $SE(3)$? Is this the direct sum of (some) bi-invariant metric on $\textrm{SO}(3)$ and the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^3$? I'd guess geodesics depend on which bi-invariant metric one chooses.

Comment: I want to know how "different" two rigid body transformations $H_1$ and $H_2$ are from one another in a simple formula.  There are probably a lot of such formulas, the one I propose might be a good or bad one, and basically the question asks you to suggest a better one.

Comment: In general it is (much) easier to specify a metric than it is to compute geodesic distances determined by that metric, and in general different metrics will lead to different geodesic distances. Since $SE(3)$ is a Lie group, it is natural to consider left-invariant metrics, which are determined by their value at a single point (usually one specifies its value at the identity). Then, for any geodesic $\gamma(t)$ and any $g \in SE(3)$, $g \cdot \gamma(t)$ is also a geodesic. This means to find geodesic distances it is enough to work out the case when one endpoint is the identity of the group.

Comment: Thanks for he response.  I think I need to do a bit more studying before I can completely understand it.

Comment: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/SE3-Croke-Kumar.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is no bi-invariant metric on $SE(3)$.  There is one bi-invariant pseudo-metric (not degenerate, but not positive definite) called the hyperbolic metric.  To calculate it you have to go to the algebra $\hat\eta\in\mathfrak{se}(3)$ associated with $h\in SE(3)$.

Taking $\hat \eta_i=\begin{bmatrix} \hat \omega & v \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix},$ and then associating $\mathfrak{se}(3)$ with $\mathbb{R}^6$, such that $\eta=\begin{bmatrix} v \\ \omega \end{bmatrix}$, the hyperbolic metric is the quadratic form $\Psi=\begin{bmatrix}0 & I_3 \\ I_3 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.  This gives $\langle \eta_1, \eta_2 \rangle_H= v_1^T\omega_2+v_2^T\omega_1.$

A good reference for this is Appendix A, Section 3.2, of *A Mathematical Introduction to Robotic Manipulation* by Murray, Li and Sastry.